# How to create a VM with a specific external IP or IP range?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, static-ip

I have some problems with some google cloud IP ranges, they are blocked in my country, so I cannot connect to my VM if the instance is on those external IP ranges. I have tried reserving IP addresses but the reservation also ends up with the similar IP ranges that are blocked. so I wanted to know if there is a way to create a VM with a specific IP or IP range, I know you can select the region, but in each region, there is more than one IP range, let's say for example for us-central there are 3 IP ranges like (34.x.x.x 35.x.x.x 104.x.x.x), but only 1 actually works for me, is there a way to create my VM, or reserve an external IP address on that range that works for me? so far I have not been able to do it.

Comment: You could try allocating IP addresses until one is in your accepted range. However, you cannot specify a specific address except for certain cases where a customer owns an IP address.

Comment: yea, that was something I didnt want to go with, as it might take a lot of tries, but I guess that's the way to go, thank you for your suggestion and help